# Batch - Loop through folders and run command

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, command

I am trying to remove Dropbox from around 500+ Windows 7 computers using a batch script. Dropbox is installed on a per-user basis under **"%APPDATA%\Dropbox"**.

To uninstall silently you have to run **"%APPDATA%\Dropbox\bin\DropboxUninstaller.exe /S"**. I have tested this command and it works fine, but the problem is it only uninstalls it from the user directory you run it from. I have tried taking the DropboxUninstaller.exe file and running it from the root of C:, but it fails.

I will be pushing this script out via SCCM, so it will run under the SYSTEM account. I need to find a way to loop between all of the user direcories, find which profiles have the Dropbox\bin\DropboxUninstaller.exe path/file and run it in that location.

I have tested logging in as another user (local admin) and running the Dropbox uninstaller from another users directory, and it uninstalls fine for the user whos directory I run it in, so I know this will work.

If anyone could help me out with the correct command, that would be great! I have googled around for an answer, but it doesn't seem to be out there.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search user profiles, and for each if unistaller exists, execute it (asumming an "standard" installation, maybe this needs to be adjusted)

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    for /F "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" /v ProfileImagePath /s ^| find "REG_EXPAND_SZ" ^| findstr /v /i "\\windows\\ \\system32\\"') do (
        call :doUninstall "%%b"
    )

    endlocal
    exit /b

:doUninstall
    set "_uninstaller=%~1\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\bin\DropboxUninstaller.exe"
    if not exist "%_uninstaller%" goto :EOF
    start "" /wait "%_uninstaller%" /S
    goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this - it's exactly what I was looking for! I am just having a few issues understanding the following parts:

1) What is the %a used for in the FOR command and the %b when it calls the uninstall?

2) findstr /v /i "\\windows\\ \\system32\\" - I have no clue whats happening in this part either?

Sorry to seem like a dunce - my scripting knowledge is limited!

Comment: The name of directory in output of reg command can contain spaces, so tokens in `for` are defined as `2,*` (2 is the reg_expland_sz text in output, * is the rest of the line, the directory). As two tokens are defined, first it accessed via the for variable %%a, the second is accessed in the next variable %%b. The findstr is to exclude from list the systemprofile, localservice and networkservice users.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /r c:\windows %A in (notepad.exe) do "%A" %windir%\win.ini
```

Remember %%A in a batch and %A at command prompt.